# Recover Wallet password (MultiBit Classic Version : 0.5.14) MAC

Tags: multibit, wallet-recovery

Back in 2013 my parents bought 2 BTC, put a password on the wallet and haven't touched it sense. I am 80% sure I have the password correct, but no luck. But they were smart enough to back up all of their info, such as the wallet-backup, the key-backup, the Wallet Unenc-backup, and a rolling backup on to CDs.

I tried to move the wallet onto other platforms, but had no luck without the password. I managed to view it on blockchain, but it's labeled as "Watch Only". The only way I can get access to it is if I do QR code scan, but my private key I can get at is a string of numbers and digits in the backup files else I can somehow turn that into a QR code. So I was thinking perhaps the password can be hidden in the .key file or can be opened though the .wallet cipher in the Unenc-backup. This version of MultiBit is old so it does not have the 12 word recovery system please help.

Comment: Without the password, you're out of luck. If you have an unencrypted backup, you should be able to recover the keys from that

Comment: on my cd labeled unencrypted back up it has a .cipher file in it no idea how to open yet alone use it.

Comment: if you check the receive wallet address on a blcokchain explorer, do you see the 2 btc?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wKGS7AY6B4 - this might help?

Answer (score 0):

The mbexport app will help with the wallet file in the unenc-backup folder - but that might not contain the main wallet key. If you try to open an encrypted wallet using mbexport, it will ask you for the password.

Sorry I can't be much more help. Without an unencrypted copy of the key, the password is the only way to get the key.

- https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/read-multibit-wallet-file
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mbexport